# Is this a sentence fragment...?

Tags: clauses, dependent-clause, sentence-fragments

Ok, so here is an example sentence.

"I hoped to lose the race so I wouldn't have to run against him."

Here's my dilemma. I was questioning whether a comma was necessary after "race" to separate the two independent clauses connected by "so," the coordinating conjunction, but then it occurred to me:

Is "I wouldn't have to run against him" an independent clause, or is it dependent? If it were standing on its own, would it be considered a fragment? Can someone please explain?

Comment: Would you include a comma in *"I say this so you'll reconsider"*? It's really just a matter of style - and you could also use a dash instead of a comma if you think the first clause is getting so long you need to give a visual indication so the reader can easily see where it ends.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by fragment, but it would certainly be appropriate to insert a comma after 'race'. They are in fact two separate sentences, joined by 'so'. Each has a main verb.

Comment: ...also note that one could contrive a context wherein the intended sense was that you *wouldn't have to run against him [in some prior event] **because** you hoped to lose the [later] race*. And I suspect no amount of fiddling with commas would disambiguate those two interpretations.

Comment: In your example: *""I hoped to lose the race so [ (that) I wouldn't have to run against him ]."* The stuff inside the brackets is a declarative content clause. It seems like you are asking whether that content clause can stand alone as an independent clause: a fully formed sentence; and if not, why not. -- That sounds like a very good question. :)

Comment: Here's an example of a declarative content clause that can't stand alone as a fully formed sentence: *"My client denies [ that he ever said any such thing ]"*, where the overall sentence is grammatical -- but compare to the ungrammatical independent clause: *"He ever said any such thing"*.

Answer (score 1):

No, the sentence is not fragmented. Broken down, it's simply two independent clauses connected with the coordinating conjunction *"so."* I wouldn't insert a comma after *"race."* It's not necessary.